# Bootstrap making columns disappear when shrinking screen size even though I specified that the columns should be present

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

All the columns with the class `side` disappear when shrinking the screen size even though I've specified that they're supposed to appear when the screen size is xs. I used the inspect element in Google Chrome and they do exist when the screen is shrunk, but they have no width. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class=top>
        <h3>Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-8 side">
            Hi
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 space"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 space"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-8 center">
            HI
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 space"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 space"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-8 side">
            Hi
        </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and I've written the CSS in Sass so here it is as an scss file (will add css file below):

```
$pagebg:lightgrey;
$primarycolor:orange;
$secondarycolor:white;
$divheight:500px;

%interests{
    height:$divheight;
    border-radius:20px;
}

.center {
    @extend %interests;
    background: $secondarycolor;
    color:$primarycolor;
}
.side {
    @extend %interests;
    background: $primarycolor;
    color:$secondarycolor;
}
.top{
    background:$primarycolor;
    color:$secondarycolor;
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom:45px;
    width:100%;
}
@media (min-width:992px){
    .space{
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:577px) and (max-width:991px){
    .space{
    height:$divheight;
    }
}
@media(max-width:576px){
    .side, .center{
    border-radius:0;
    }
}
```

Here is the pure css:

```
.side, .center {
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.center {
  background: white;
  color: orange;
}

.side {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}

.top {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .space {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 577px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .space {
    height: 500px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .side, .center {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: the code above works fine with me try clearing your cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to include this `Meta Tag` in your HTML, in order to make the Google Chrome dev tool work, Especially reposive one!

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In your **style.css** file, Code shows that you are disappearing all the divs containing class of `space` not the class of `side`.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .space {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But you have mentioned in your question that div containing class of `side` are disappearing. So if you want to make all divs containing class name `side` disappeared, then you have to include this code in your css.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .side {
    display: none;
  }
}
```